# pattern matching using regex in groovy

Tags: java, regex, groovy

I have the below groovy code

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

String myInput="License_All (12313)"
String myRegex="\\(\\d+\\)"


String ResultString
Pattern regex
Matcher regexMatcher

regex = Pattern.compile(myRegex, Pattern.DOTALL);

regexMatcher = regex.matcher(myInput);

List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
matchList.add(regexMatcher.group());
}

for(int i=0;i<matchList.size();i++)
{
myInput=myInput.replaceAll( matchList[i], '')
println matchList[i]
}
println myInput
```

It is supposed to remove `(12313)` part but instead it gives me the below output

```
(12313)
License_All ()
```

How do i remove all the bracket portion `(12313)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `matchList` will contain the matched part, i.e. `(12313)`. This one is then again taken as regular expression within `replaceAll` and therefore interpreted as group. Thus the brackets are not removed.

Instead you can use your regex directly in `replaceAll`:

```
myInput.replaceAll(myRegex, "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Becaue you are using `replaceAll`, it is expecting a `Pattern` as the first element

```
myInput = myInput.replaceAll( Pattern.compile(myRegex, Pattern.DOTALL), '' )
```

Should do it...

---

As an aside, your original code can be made into more idiomatic Groovy (rather than basically Java) like so -- obviously, this has the same issue as in your original question, it's just a more Groovy way of writing code:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern

String myInput = "License_All (12313)"

def regex = Pattern.compile( /\(\d+\)/, Pattern.DOTALL);

List<String> matchList = ( myInput =~ regex ) as List

matchList.each { m ->
  myInput = myInput.replaceAll( m, '')
  println m
}
println myInput
```